# Equivalent of "Yii::app()->runController('controller/action')" in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

What is the equivalent function of:

```
Yii::app()->runController('controller/action')
```

in Yii2? I would like to call a action from another controller in current controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This may work:

```
Yii::$app->runAction('controller/action');
```

Comment: Hey can i pass the Http method to execute in the runAction?

Comment: can we use like this for sending param?

Yii::$app->runAction('controller/action');

Comment: Try this way 

    Yii::$app->runAction('main/goods', ['model_id' => $goods->id]);

In MainController 
    public function actionGoods($model_id)
    {
        ..... yuor code
    }

Comment: should it be like `Yii::$app->runAction('metercontroller/create');` or `Yii::$app->runAction('meter/create');` ?

Comment: You get the point - 'controller/action' shall be substituted with your app controller and method names !

Comment: Thank you, Peter, felipe. :-)